# how to share data in two different lines in description parameter in facebook using php

Tags: facebook, sdk, sharing

Hi i'm using facebook php sdk 5.0 for sharing data , and successfully  implemented it , but , i'm facing a problem while displaying content in two different lines in description parameter .Lest say  description parameter contains "1. description 
 2. description " . But when it get posted it is not breaking the line or showing in new line for "2. description" . Please help i need to know how to solve this.

Comment: Simply not possible.

Comment: Are you sure on your comment CBroe , i need a confirmation that it  is  not possible , or if any solution for this problem

Comment: You can try with `<center></center>` as mentioned in an answer to the other question – but I am not sure if that still works. And even if it does, it’s ugly – and might stop working at any point in the future. You are really better off to accept that Facebook obviously doesn’t _want_ developers to mess with the layout.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe , i will try once more  with <center>